# Is there a way to use Matlab to convert a .RAW audio file to .wav?

Tags: matlab, wav

I have a folder of audio files, stored in the `.RAW` format. In order to use the `audioread` function I need these to be in the `.wav` format, but can't seem to find a way to convert them.

The machine that the files are stored on is not connected to the internet, so I can't use an online converter. I have Matlab 2020b, on Windows 10. I have four toolboxes:

- Signal Processing
- DSP System
- Image Processing
- Parallel computing

Comment: .raw just mean that your audio file is not compressed, it is not a standard format that respect some rules. Do you know how this file was produced ? Do you know what is the sampling frequency, the number of channel ... ?

Comment: @obchardon There are three channels for all the files. I know the sampling frequency as I know the number of datapoints and the time period that was sampled for when the data was collected.

Comment: So you can already calculate the bit depth (bit precision) of your .raw file `bit_depth = file_size_in_bits/(num_channel*Fs*audio_duration_in_seconds)`. Now read your file with `fread()`, something like `my_audio_data = fread(file,file_size_in_bits/bit_depth,uint16)` (where uint16 should be adjusted according to the bit_depth). Now it should be easy to determine the file structure (are the channels interleaved or blocked or ...). Finally reshape your audio signal in order to create a `Nx3` vector and use audiowrite to create the .wav file.

Comment: And if you could provide one of this audio file, it could help.

Comment: @obchardon I can't provide an audio file because they're stored on a machine with no internet access. Your previous comment looks like exactly what I'm after though - thank you!